# Operator << for QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

It makes sense to implement << for QString like:

```
std::ostream&  operator <<(std::ostream &stream,const QString &str)
{
   stream << str.toAscii().constData(); //or: stream << str.toStdString(); //??
   return stream;
}
```

instead of writing

```
stream << str.toAscii().constData();
```

every time in the code.

However, since it is not in standard Qt library, I'm assuming there is any particular reason not to do so. What are the risks/inconvenience of overloading << as specified above?

Comment: I don't see why it makes sense to use str.toAscii() instead of toLatin1() or toUtf8() or toLocal8Bit() ?

Comment: @fjardon - there is no particular reason :) Any of the ones you mentioned I think would work to.

Comment: They do very different things outside of 7-bit clean strings.

Comment: I believe the reason it's not in Qt is that Qt is pretty much trying to replace the entire standard library with itself. Not that I like this philosophy of theirs, but they seem keen on it.

Comment: @Yakk, do you mean << would be not cross-platform, so it is not in standard Qt library? I wonder, is it not possible to implement << for the cases you mention? Say std::string has <<...

Comment: `std::basic_ostream` sounds like a better thing to overload.  Then toss some traits classes to figure out how to get the right bit-width of `char*` from your `QString`.

Comment: @Ilya I mean: there can be only a single operator << for QString and ostream. And there is no reason to restrict the library users to only one implementation. So it should not be included in the library but let to each user initiative to write this operator.

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy no, I mean that `toAscii` and `toLatin1` or `toUtf8` or `toLocal8Bit` do very different things outside of a '7 bit clean' character string (a character string where only the lowest 7 bits are ever used) (and sometimes do different things even on 7 bit clean strings).

Comment: Another thing to consider: locale.  I'd be tempted to use utf8 for narrow `basic_ostream` and utf16 for wide `basic_ostream` and do proper locale conversion from either of those to the locale of the stream.  I'm not an expert on C++ standard library locale functions, however I'd start looking at [codecvt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) and [basic_streambuf::getloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/getloc) and research from there.

Comment: Note that you can also use qPrintable(str). Saves some typing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the `<<` operator is included in the Qt library every client of the library will have to use the exact same implementation. But due to the nature of QString it is far from obvious this is what these clients want. Some people writing software interacting with legacy file in western europe may want to use Latin1() characters, US people may go with Ascii() and more modern software may want to use Utf8().

Having a single implementation in the library would restrict unacceptably what can be done with the whole library.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that makes sense - I take it as it is not the width of the bit that can't be figured out, but same bit width can be treated differently depending on the underlying text that QString represent. However, it is safe to provide own implementation for << knowing what character encoding maps to, right?

Comment: Yes, if you know you will only deal with Ascii you can create your own operator.

Answer (score 12):

It's not necessary to implement such thing, as long as there exists a convenient solution like this one, involving [QTextStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html)

```
QString s;
QTextStream out(&s);
out << "Text 1";
out << "Text 2";
out << "And so on....";
```

[QTextStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html) is quite powerfull...

Comment: ...unless the interface you must work with requires a `std::ostream` of course.

Comment: There are something wrong in the provide source code. After do "QTextStream out(&s);" you can do out << "Text1" no s << "Text1"

Answer (score 4):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281774/434551) points out some valid reasons for why there is no `operator<<` function for `QString`.

One can easily overcome those reasons by providing some convenience functions and maintaining some state in an application specific `namespace`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>

namespace MyApp
{
   typedef char const* (*QStringInsertFunction)(QString const& s);

   char const* use_toAscii(QString const& s)
   {
      return s.toAscii().constData();
   }

   char const* use_toUtf8(QString const& s)
   {
      return s.toUtf8().constData();
   }

   char const* use_toLatin1(QString const& s)
   {
      return s.toLatin1().constData();
   }

   // Default function to use to insert a QString.
   QStringInsertFunction insertFunction = use_toAscii;

   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, QStringInsertFunction fun)
   {
      insertFunction = fun;
      return out;
   }

   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, QString const& s)
   {
      return out << insertFunction(s);
   }
};

int main()
{
   using namespace MyApp;

   QString testQ("test-string");

   std::cout << use_toAscii << testQ << std::endl;
   std::cout << use_toUtf8 << testQ << std::endl;
   std::cout << use_toLatin1 << testQ << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test-string
test-string
test-string
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any particular reason for excluding (nor including) this in the `Qt library`. Only problem that could possibly appear here is a possibility that `std::ostream` object could modify the contents of the parameter passed to `std::ostream::operator<<` function.

However, in the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) it is clearly stated that this function will modify the parameter if string buffer is passed - there is nothing about the other types, so I guess (and the common-sense is telling me) that operator<< will not modify `char*` parameter. Also, on [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) page there is nothing about modifying the passed object.

Last thing: instead of using `QString::toAscii().constData()`, you could use `QString::toStdString()` or `qPrintable(const QString&)` macro.